# Can not commit to sign with gpg2 on Windows 10 (GnuPG)

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I'm trying to generate keys and sign the commit. My key list:

`gpg2 --list-keys`:

```
C:/Users/raski/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.gpg

------------------------------------------------
pub   2048R/8E3A3251 2016-11-26
uid       [ultimate] My Name <raski@example.com>
sub   2048R/29C8D116 2016-11-26
```

`git config --global -l`:

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=roma
user.email=raski@example.com
user.signingkey=8E3A3251
commit.gpgsign=true
gpg.program=D:/Programs/GnuPG/pub/gpg2
```

I try make a commit:

```
git commit -m "initial"
```

Previously, I add my public PGP key in the settings Github. But, I've error:

```
gpg: skipped "2048R/8E3A3251": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

It is why it is still using gpg, instead of gpg 2, although I have configured the path to gpg2. What can be the problem exists?

Comment: What's `gpg2 -K` (aka `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`) say?  You're only showing the public half here.

Comment: I get the same error. Does gpg --version tell you the old versionin Git Bash?

Answer (score 2):

> It is why it is still using gpg, instead of gpg 2, although I have configured the path to gpg2.

That would be because git for windows itself does include a `gpg.exe` 1.x in its `<git>/usr/bin` folder, used by `git` commands.

> What can be the problem exists?

You need in your `<gpg2>\latest\pub` folder to copy `gpg2.exe` into a `gpg.exe`, that way the `PATH` might actually include a `gpg.exe` 2.x before the `gpg.exe` 1.x from `git`.
Or, if it does not work, copy `<gpg2>\latest\pub\gpg2.exe` into a `<git>/usr/bin/gpg.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `gpg.exe` file under `<git>/usr/bin`.

Comment: You'll need to remember to redelete `gpg.exe` when you upgrade git for windows.